# AngularJs AutoComplete in 1.0 using json object

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

i need an example for AngularJs AutoComplete in 1.0 using json object.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Bootstrap typeahead http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Check this plunker done a simple solution for the auto complete : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/il2J8qOI2Dr7Ik1KHRm8?p=preview